# Ajax Timer loading problem

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax, timer

I am using ajax timer in my program for an online test application. Program working as expected.

However Ajax timer is calculating the page load time also. For example if I allocate 20 seconds to one question, after the page load user will get less time than 20 seconds as it will calculate the loading time.

Is there any way I can disable the timer and enable it again only after the full page load.
Or is there any C# code to find out whether the page is fully loaded or not??

Thanks,
Jithu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is expected behavior. The timer's placement within a container determines the amount of time it takes to trigger between intervals. For instance, if it's placed within an UpdatePanel it will take take the time to load the contents of the UpdatePanel after the first trigger + the interval to set the next interval.

If the timer exists on the main page itself, and it's the Load event that takes a long time to process, you could then try 
doing `timer.Start()` on the `OnLoadComplete` event of the page.

Comment: Hi arvi, Thank you for your ideas, Here exact problem is during postback, the users are complaining that they loosing 5-6 seconds. FOr example I have a next button to go for the next question. Onclick it is diducting the load time also... How can I calculate that time lap. I meant the loading time,so that I can add that with the actual Time :)

Comment: You don't _have_ to calculate the time it takes to process the page load/click events. The reason being that if you start your timer during the `OnLoadComplete`, the timer starts _after_ the control events are processed. I'd suggest you check the ASP.NET page life cycle model to see why.